# Monkey Talk IDE doesn't record actions

Tags: android, testing, monkey

I'm trying to use Monkey Talk for automation test. I installed it successfully. I run the sample app on Eclipse Juno then create a new Monkey script and record actions. **The problem is Monkey IDE doesn't record my actions on device or emulator**. I tried both of them but not lucky. How to fix?

Eclipse Juno, Ubuntu OS.

[I followed this tutorial video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJTxZdkO_4k)

Screenshot when connected to my device via device ip address.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure the monkey talk android agent is added to your libs folder, also your project has converted to Aspectj.

Comment: Of course I did. I read the Monkey Talk forum. This is the well-known problem in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with iOS simulator or Device but when i restart Monkey IDE it, configure the connection to your device , after a second the recording feature is enabled. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Monkey Talk IDE with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to make your app source code compatible with Monkeytalk by below steps and after than you can automate it steps are :

1. Download MonkeyTalk for gorilla logic website and unzip it.
2. Open Eclipse and convert your project on "Aspectj" (need a plugin aspectj - for eclipse)- Once it get downloaded right click on your app, configure, Convert to aspectj.
3. Then under your project folder structure search for "libs" folder if it's exist then ok else create it.
4. Once it get done go to monkeytalk, agents, android, Monkeytalkjar file. Copy it and paste it under libs folder.
5. Once it done click on "jar" file and right click on it, Aspectjtools, Add to aspectpath.
6. Then go to Androidmanifest.xml file where we have to add some permissions;

   `<Uses-permissions android:name="android.Permission.INTERNET/>`

   `<Uses-permissions android:name="android.Permission.Get_TASKS/>`

and save it.

7. Go to project click on it, Right click, properties, JavaBuild Path, Check the "Aspectj Runtime Library, Ok.
8. Run your application as a Android application.
9. Open monkey talk.
10. Create new project, Create new script.
11. Then set the android sdk path under prefences; MonkeyTalk, MonketTalkPrefences, Android SDK path, ok.
12. Connect to emulator on monkeytalk.

Now you will be able to record and play in MonkeyTalk.

Some start up code for your reference eg; if we have two textfield username and password and one button submit.

```
app.input("username").entertext("aakash");

app.input("password").entertext("jaiswal");

app.button("submit").tap();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I successfully did

1) see what is your eclipse version from (Help->About ADT) or (Help->About Eclipse)

2) get the url of AspectJ from this url https://eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/

3) goto Help->Install New Software and add the path

install the software and enjoy! see the video for detail help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJMUgOrffFY

4) add monkey talk jar file in libs folder, if there is not libs folder in your project make one and add the monkeytalk jar file that is in the zip folder you downloaded

5) add the monkey talk jar in build path or right click at add it to aspectpath

6) add permission in manifest.xml
  android.permission.INTERNET
  android.permission.GET_TASKS

7) Then go to Androidmanifest.xml file where we have to add some permissions;

and save it.

8) Go to project click on it,Right click,properties,JavaBuild Path,Check the "Aspectj Runtime Library,Ok.

9) Run your application.

10) Open monkey talk IDE.

11) Create new project and script file.

12) set sdk path and set the connection to emulator

12) click connect to emulator or the device

now you can see the record button enable, for details see this https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/android

Hope it helps, feel free to ask if there is anything that is still not working.