# Androidmanifest.xml file is not available in project in Eclipse

Tags: android

I am using MonkeyTalk tool for Mobile testing for Android n folllowed the procedure given in it, I had created java project in Eclipse then downloaded Android plugin then converted the project into ASpectJ project by installing AJDT , n all the procedure but Androidmanifest.xml file is not available in the project.

Need help for this

Answer (score 0):

use clean refresh restarting eclipse as your saying u didn't skipped a line . the developers out there created monkey talk might have tested several times before publishing it

Answer (score 0):

when you create the android project the AndroidManifest.xml is made by default, if you can't see the android manifest file either clean your porject. I have successfully integrated monkey talk in my android application see the posted answer here [Monkey Talk IDE doesn't record actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854279/monkey-talk-ide-doesnt-record-actions/29426655#29426655) hope it helps.