# It is not possible to instrument the App in monkey talk pro

Tags: android, monkeytalk

When I am trying to instrument the App in monkey talk it shows the following error in the console. anyone know how to solve it?

```
 : ERROR: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)

instrumented APK file was not created at: /tmp/tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1398773468466_12/Caprabo_Modified/bin/Caprabo_Modified-debug.apk

Error instrumenting apk '/home/nandakishore/Desktop/Caprabo_Modified.apk': instrumented APK file was not created at: /tmp/tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1398773468466_12/Caprabo_Modified/bin/Caprabo_Modified-debug.apk

    com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor$InstrumentationException: instrumented APK file was not created at: /tmp/tmp_AndroidInstrumentor1398773468466_12/Caprabo_Modified/bin/Caprabo_Modified-debug.apk
        at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor.copyInstrumentedApk(AndroidInstrumentor.java:235)
        at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor.beginInstrumentation(AndroidInstrumentor.java:199)
        at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.instrumentor.android.AndroidInstrumentor.instrumentApk(AndroidInstrumentor.java:130)
        at com.gorillalogic.monkeytalk.ide.instrumentor.InstrumentApkAction$InstrumentApkJob.run(InstrumentApkAction.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: i have successfully integrated monkey talk in my android application see the posted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854279/monkey-talk-ide-doesnt-record-actions/29426655#29426655 hope it helps