# How to enable record button in monkey talk on initial phase(for launching an app)

Tags: automation, monkeytalk

I need to record script for launching(splash screen) an app but not able to do that on Monkey talk.

Thanks regards,
Arihant

Comment: i have successfully integrated monkey talk in my android application see the posted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854279/monkey-talk-ide-doesnt-record-actions/29426655#29426655 hope it helps

Comment: Hi Syed, I am trying to login with facebook but while connecting to facebook and come back to my app, app is getting crashed because of splash/launch screen. So is there any way to proceed further or is there any way to access splash screen in Monkey talk. Please reply.

Comment: what i suggest you to do is made septate scripts file, i don't think we can access splash screen but what we can do is make a septate script file for the flow after crash and then run it. Actually we can access the action on a view in monkey talk

Comment: Can we create accessibility label for any screen image(like splash screen) and use. If we can create then how can we use it. Please provide me with detail.

Comment: Hi Syed, have you any idea about accessibility label?if.. Please provide me necessary detail for this issue. or can we do something else for this.

Comment: Arihant i have to look into this right now my friend i don't know. I have worked on button, action like swipe but i never want the label for a screen for anything. I will look into it then i will let you know.